# SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1051)

Tags: python-3.x, requests, openssl, anaconda

Всем привет! Нагуглить пока не удалось. В общем проблема такая при парсинге сайта получаю ошибку `SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR] tlsv1 alert internal error (_ssl.c:1051)` , версия  `OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018`. Запрос делаю простым способом

```
url = requests.get(url.strip(), timeout=200, verify=False, headers = headers)`
```

При просмотре версии python3 `"import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"` всплывает такая ошибка http://prntscr.com/pawtja

```
"python3" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ© Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Кст, `Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ© Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.` это `е является внутренней или внешней ком ндой, исполняемой прогр ммой или п кетным ф йлом.`

Comment: @gil9red Так делоть то, что? Как лечить проблему с ошибкой? ;)

Comment: Попробуйте `pip install requests[security]`

Comment: @gil9red не получается, ломается например на сайте rs = requests.get('https://www.MOSseo.ru/') 
У меня ощущение, что проблема в Анаконде